# XML File is generated when i build an application in c#.net visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, app-config, crystal-reports-2010

When I Build an application, an .xml file is generated in the build path having a same name as my application executable.

I opened the xml file and found it contains the lines from app.config which I wrote.

why is this so? how can I embed app.config in my application? 
 Actually if I donot copy the xml file in the deployment my application does not open crystal reports and application halts.

content of app.config which I wrote :

```
<!--<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">


  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>-->

  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">

  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/></startup>
```

Please Let me know how can app.config embedded in the executable!

Comment: That's the app config, it is simply copied and renamed!

Comment: What is the exact name (extension included) of this file?

Comment: @Gerrie Schenck : Yes it is the same app config file. But if the XML file is not present in the deployment folder my application does not work! how can I embed it in my application?

Comment: @Steve : It is the same name which my executable has. i.e. omsxyx.exe and the xml file name is omsxyz.xml. I want to embed the config file in my Executable so that I don't need to copy the XML file separately in the deployment folder.

Comment: This is strange. The normal behavior is to have a file name omsxyx.exe.config that is a copy of the app.config located in the project folder. This file is needed by the NET framework infrastructure when you launch you application. Please check the property of the file APP.CONFIG in your solution explorer and eventually reset to their default values

Comment: You *don't* embed the app.config in your application. It's *meant* to be a separate file.